# Iphone App to display the uibutton Transition

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.2

I have done one iphone app regarding Flip Horizontal Transition.But i click on button means the total view will be transition.but i want only button transition on the view.please give solution .i use ios sdk5,xcode 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

You can transition one sub view to another as in this example:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:fromView
                    toView:toView
                  duration:0.70
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                               ....
                           }];
```

This will flip the sub view (which can be a button) and replace it with the new one.